# Importing data into DatagridComboBoxColumn does not update combo list value

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, mvvm, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I build a DataGrid the contains a custom ComboBoxColumn that shows and selects the proper fields when I select it with a mouse, but resets to the first item in the list after the ComboBox loses focus.  Additionally, when when I import data from an Excel spreadsheet, the ComboBox does not change to match the value in the worksheet.

Note: I'm planning on reusing this class to create a series of ComboBoxes for different data.

What is preventing the Combo Box from accepting a new value?

ComboList class

```
namespace x.Models
{
  public class ComboList
  {
    public int FieldID {get;set;}
    public string FieldString {get;set;}
  }
}
```

XAML Combo Box code

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Platform Type" x:Name="PlatformTable" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding FieldID}" DisplayMemberPath="FieldString" SelectedValuePath="1" />
```

Code(behind)

```
public partial class MainWindow: Window
{
  public ObservableCollection<Models.ComboList> PlatformCombo {get;set;}
  public MainWindow()
  {
    PlatformCombo = new ObservableCollection<Models.ComboList>()
    {
      new Models.ComboList() {FieldID=1,FieldString="Mounted"},
      new Models.ComboList() {FieldID=2,FieldString="Dismounted"}
    };
    PlatformTable.ItemsSource = PlatformCombo;
}
```

Sample Excel data

```
Platform Type
1
2
```

Comment: I have added UpdateSourceTrigger and Mode to the SelectedValueBinding, but I am seeing the same problems:
    `SelectedValueBinding="{Binding FieldID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XAML Combo Box `SelectedValueBinding` must be set to the DataGrid Combo Box Control Name instead of the generic Combo Box `FieldID` and the `UpdateSourceTrigger` needs to be set to `LostFocus`.

`SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Platform_Type, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"`

Answer (score 0):

Changing `SelectedValueBinding` to `SelectedItemBinding` fixes one part of the problem on the field not accepting a new value. [link] ([DataGridComboBoxColumn not updating model WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629345/datagridcomboboxcolumn-not-updating-model-wpf))

I'm still left with the question as to why when importing from Excel, the combo box is never updated; left empty for each row, even though there is appropriate data for the combo box.